# How to apply style rules that are tied to a model in AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am building an application which sends 1-5 views and the appropriate model&controller to the client on page load. The user is guided to each view consecutively using routing and this is working just fine.

The problem I have is that I want to apply style rules to the view, but the style rules are tied to the **model**. I know that I cannot simply save some css as text and inject them into a `<style></style>` block. I cannot simply add a reference to a .css file because all of this is coming from a database, and each model could potentially have style rules that conflict with another model.

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: See [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and you're able to bind it to an object of style class name properties to booleans indicating their applied state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* insert a style element into the page:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.css = ".red { color: red;}"
})
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var style = angular.element('<style type="text/css"></style>');
      style.append(scope.css);
      elem.append(style);
    }
  }
});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1KTCjXJfIM45pMYxQJc?p=preview)

Comment: is there a way to get this to work in IE8? I've tried throwing all the IE8 best practices at this problem and it is still not working.

Comment: Here, it will work in IE (but won't in other browsers): http://plnkr.co/edit/C37kCWFAfE8VAvUt0bQF?p=preview I'll leave the real work of making it work in both places to you ;-)

Comment: ..meaning you should be able to combine the two solutions

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using ng-class.  If you can get your css rules out of the database and into a $scope object like this:

```
$scope.css = {
    divcss:{
      'border-style': 'solid',
      'border-width': '2px',
      'background-color': 'yellow'
    },
    headercss:{
      'font-weight': 'bold',
      'font-size': '50px'
    }
  }
```

Then you can apply them to your view element like this:

```
<div ng-style="css.divcss">Check it out</div>
<span ng-style="css.headercss">Big ol' Header</span>
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/B1gkChhxn9yllVrbvwHN?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Jerrad. This probably wouldn't work for what we are trying to do since the css code has to be formatted in json, which I should have mentioned in the question.